# Trying to read checkboxes in shiny, R; gives "Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed"

Tags: r, shiny

When I try I'm trying to create a Shiny app, but when I add and try to use check-boxes, my code fails and I get the following error upon clicking "Run App" in RStudio. It has something to do with the way I'm reading my checkboxes in, but I cannot figure out what. I tried changing the checkbox values to a list, adding "session" as a parameter in my server.R file based on similar StackOverflow questions, but nothing's working.

> Error in `$.shinyoutput`(output, value) : 
>   Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.

My ui.r File:

```
<pre>
<code>
shinyUI(navbarPage('CERELAS AAHHHHHH',
    tabPanel('Scatter', titlePanel('cereal'),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        fluidPage(
            checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"),
            choices = list("Nabisco" = 'N',                                          
                           "American Home Food Products" = 'A',
                           "General Mills" = 'G',
                           "Kelloggs" = 'K',
                           "Post" = 'P',
                           "Quaker Oats" = 'Q',
                           "Ralston Purina" = 'R'
                           ),
                           selected = 'N'),

                           hr(),
                           fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

                                )                              
                                ),

                              mainPanel(
                                #give your plot a descriptive name
                                plotlyOutput("scatter")
                              )
                            )

                   )
))

</code>
</pre>
```

My server.R file:

```
<pre>
<code>
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$value <- renderText({ input$checkGroup })
  print(output$value)
  # Render a plotly object that returns your map
  output$scatter <- renderPlotly({
    df <- read.delim(file = 'data/cereal.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
    #return some plot
  })
})
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: just remove `print(output$value)` : as message says, you can't read `output`

Comment: but you can do : `output$value <- renderText({ print(input$checkGroup) })`